# Polymer's two way data-binding not working in an element's child's attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, polymer

I have a `product-card` custom element that looks like this:

```
<dom-module id="product-card">    
   <template>
    <div class="card-main-content layout horizontal center">
      <content select="img"></content>
      <content select="h3"></content>
      <content select="h4"></content>
    </div>
    <content></content>
    <paper-icon-button id="carticon" icon="add-shopping-cart" on-tap="cartTapped">
    </paper-icon-button>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
(function() {
  Polymer({
  is: 'product-card',

  properties: {
    host: {
      type: String,
      notify:true,
      reflectToAttribute: true,
      value: "http://localhost:3003"
    },
    imagepath: {
      type: String,
      notify: true,
      reflectToAttribute: true
    },
    imageurl: {
      type: String,
      notify: true,
      reflectToAttribute: true,
      computed: 'computeImageUrl(host, imagepath)'
   }
  },

  cartTapped: function(event) {
    /*...............*/
    this.fire('cart-tap');
  },

    computeImageUrl: function(host, imagepath) {
     return host+imagepath;
    }
  });
  })();
</script>
```

This element is used in another custom element called `product-list` like this:

```
<dom-module id="product-list">
  <template>
    <get-products-service products="{{products}}" id="productservice"></get-products-service>
    <div>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{products}}">
        <product-card on-cart-tap="handleCart" imagepath="{{item.master.images.0.small_url}}">
          <img src="{{imageurl}}" width="100" height="100">
          <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
          <h4>{{item.display_price}}</h4>
       </product-card>
     </template>
    </div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

The problem i have is that the `src={{imageurl}}` resolves to null. The `imageurl` is being calculated as i can see the expected values being reflected on the attributes when i inspect with chrome's developer tools. Just to add, when i add an `imageurl` attribute like this:

```
<product-card on-cart-tap="handleCart" imagepath="{{item.master.images.0.small_url}}" imageurl="{{imageurl}}">
  <img src="{{imageurl}}" width="100" height="100">
  <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
  <h4>{{item.display_price}}</h4>
</product-card>
```

I get a url of the first product's image which does not change as the product's array is iterated on. This results to loading of the same image for all products which is not the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. Right now I am also struggling to understand how to use binding within the light dom. If I find a solution, I will be sure to post it here.

You could move the image insertion out of the product-list component and into the product-card element. It is not what you are looking for in terms of flexibility, but you get the desired effect.

```
<dom-module id="product-card">    
<template>
<div class="card-main-content layout horizontal center">
  <img src="{{imageurl}}" width="100" height="100">
  <content select="h3"></content>
  <content select="h4"></content>
</div>
<content></content>
<paper-icon-button id="carticon" icon="add-shopping-cart" on-tap="cartTapped">
</paper-icon-button>
</template>
</dom-module>
```

Another 'hacky' way of getting your desired result is to set the image src in the ready callback of the lifecycle. Access the image element inside lightdom by using `Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('img')` and set the src of your computed value. Accessing the lightdom using various selectors is described in [Local DOM Basics and API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#dom-api-examples)Add the ready function to your product-card element:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'product-card',
  ready: function() {
      Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('img').src = this.imageurl;
  },
  properties: {
    host: {
      type: String,
      notify:true,
      reflectToAttribute: true,
      value: "http://lorempixel.com/50/50"
    },
...
```

Comment: I'm still very new to polymer and the whole web components concept, I'm therefore still struggling to understand the various doms. I would have wished to have the image in the dom distribution but your answer solves my immediate problem.

Comment: Then the second part of my answer might be right for you. Just add the ready function to product-card, and set the src of the image. This way, you can add your image the same way as you did in your initial solution.

Comment: Thanks, i had avoided the second method because you said it was 'hacky', but I've tested it and it works fine.

Comment: I just found how to access the lightdom elements more effectively. Instead of setting the src of the image tag with 'this.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.src = this.imageurl' in your ready function, you can use 'Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('img').src = this.imageurl'. This selects the image tag from the lightdom and sets the src to your computed value. I have updated my answer.

Comment: This seems more concise, and I dont have to worry about adding more elements above the `img` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try `src$="{{imageurl}}"`, as this will bind to the `src` attribute rather than the `src` property.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding

Comment: This only works when the `imageurl` attribute on the element is not dynamic. i.e when i do `<product-card imageurl="{{imageurl}}"...>``</product-card>` the `imageurl` is not calculated dynamically the value is the same for all items in the array and the `src` attribute is set to this value. but when i do `<product-card imageurl$="{{imageurl}}"...>``</product-card>` the `imageurl` is calculated dynamically the way i want it but the value of the `src` attributed is null. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Should it be `src$="{{item.imageurl}}"`?

Comment: `imageurl` is a computed property of the `host` property and `item.url`. what is in the item is a path, for example: `/images/productId.jpg`. the `imageurl` property is calculated by `host`+`imagepath`. For example if `host` is `"http://localhost:3003"` and `imagepath` (which is `item.url`) is `"/images/1.jpg"` the `imageurl` should be `"http://localhost:3003/images/1.jpg"` and this is the value i expect in the `src` attribute.